# How to perform the second callback after the completion first one in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, web-applications

I have googled a lot of sites to get a way to do sequential callbacks that is the second function should execute only after the completion of first function. In my case i am updating some properties of the nodes in button click and each property updation should perform a single callback. My problem is that some of property updates are based on the previous properties and i cant achieve this ..since the javascript execute all in one.

So please point me out in the correct direction..how to perform the callbacks after the completion previous call backs.

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code :

```
function SetProperties() {
        var nodes = Control1.GetNodesList();
        var ColorStyle = {
            Color: 'Red',
            ForeColor: 'Maroon',
            ColorAlphaFactor: '255',
            ForeColorAlphaFactor: '255',
            Type: '2',                
            PathBrushStyle: '1'
        };

         var LineStyle = {                
            LineColor: 'Blue',
            LineWidth: '2'
         };

         Control1.SetColorStyle(nodes[0].FullName, ColorStyle);
         Control1.SetLocation(nodes[0], 150, 300);
         Control1.SetRadius(nodes[0], 20);
         Control1.SetShading(nodes[0], true);
         Control1.SetSize(nodes[0], 150, 150);
         Control1.SetLabel(nodes[0], label);            
         Control1.SetLineStyle(nodes[0], LineStyle);
    }
```

Comment: Where is the javascript?

Comment: Please update your question to clarify a problem you have. Right now it is not clear what is wrong here. Besides, functions in JS are executed one by one anyway. JS always works in a single thread. So, if you call `function1(); function2()` function2 will be executed ONLY after `function1` is done

Comment: Also, how do you call callbacks now? Actually, you can register all callbacks in some array and execute them one after another in for loop.

Answer (score 0):

If understand, you could define hidden field in your page

```
<input type='hidden' runat='server' id='funToCall'/>
```

then you could create switch in your javascript

```
var funToCall=<% funToCall.Value %>;
switch(funToCall){
   case "fun1": Control1.SetColorStyle(nodes[0].FullName, ColorStyle); break;
   case "fun2": Control1.SetLocation(nodes[0], 150, 300); break;
...
}
```

and in code behind define which is next function to call in every postback

```
funToCall.Value="next fun...";
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your first callback function works. The JavaScript doesn't actually execute all at once, it executes sequentially in a single thread. If your first callback does all its work in one series of commands then the next piece of code will only start executing once this is done.

For example:

```
var a = 0;

function fun1() {
    a = 1;
}

function fun2() {
    alert(a);
}

fun1();
fun2();
```

Will give the same result as:

```
var a = 0;
a = 1;
alert(a);
```

Because `fun2` will be executed after `fun1` has finished executing.